# Please help me understand "The Weak Nullstellensatz."

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, polynomial-rings

I'm studying Lovett. "*Abstract Algebra*." Chapter 12. Multivariable Polynomial Rings. Section 3. The Nullstellensatz.

The book deduces The weak nullstellensatz from proposition 12.3.2. The author doesn't give proof for the weak nullstellensatz.

> **Proposition 12.3.2** $\;$ Let $F$ be a field and let $E$ be a finitely generated $F$-algebra. If $E$ is a field then it is a finite extension of $F$.
>
> **Theorem 12.3.3 (The Weak Nullstellensatz)** $\;$ Let $F$ be a field and let $R$ be a finitely generated $F$-algebra. Let $M$ be a maximal ideal of $R$. Then the field $R/M$ is a finite extension of $F$. In particular, if $F$ is algebraically closed, then $R/M \cong F$.

I don't understand two parts (Actually there are more that I don't understand but I think I can solve the rest myself once I understand these two parts).

1) Why is $R$ a ring? To talk about the ideal in $R$, $R$ should be a ring. I think the author is assuming that $(R, +, [,])$ is a ring in the $F$-algebra structure $(F, +, \times, R, + \cdot, [,])$, where the first $+$ and $\times$ are addition and multiplication in $F$, the second $+$ is an addition in $R$, $\cdot$ is a scalar multiplication, and $[,]$ is an $F$-bilinear map in $R$. I know that if $[,]$ is associative then $R$ is a ring. But I can't prove that.

2) Why is $R/M$ an $F$-algebra? To deduce that $R/M$ is a fiinite extension of $F$ from proposition 12.3.2, $R/M$ should be a finitely generated $F$-algebra. I think the author is assuming that $(F, +, \times, R/M, +, \cdot, [,])$ is an $F$-algebra structure, where for the second $+$,
$$+: R/M \times R/M \to R/M, (\overline{r_1}, \overline{r_2}) \mapsto \overline{r_1 + r_2},$$
$$\cdot: F \times R/M \to R/M, (f, \overline{r}) \mapsto \overline{fr},$$ and
$$[,]:R/M \times R/M \to R/M, (\overline{r_1}, \overline{r_2}) \mapsto \overline{r_1 r_2}.$$
But if $\cdot$ is to be well-defined, shouldn't $M$ be a submodule of $R$? I don't see why $M$ is a submodule.

Comment: How is an $F$-algebra defined?

Comment: @Kenny Let $R$ be a commutative ring. An $R$-algebra is a pair $(M, [,])$ where $M$ is an $R$-module $M$ and where $[,]$ is a $R$-bilinear map $[,]: M \times M \to M$.

Comment: @Kenny $R$-bilinear map is defined as follows:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $M$, $N$, $P$ be three $R$-modules. A function $\varphi: M \times N \to P$ is called *bilinear* if

(1) $\varphi(m_1+m_2,n)=\varphi(m_1,n)+\varphi(m_2,n)$ for all $m_1,m_2\in M$ and all $n\in N$; (2) $\varphi(rm,n)=r\varphi(m,n)$ for all $r\in R$, all $m\in M$, and all $n\in N$; (3) $\varphi(m,n_1+n_2)=\varphi(m,n_1)+\varphi(m,n_2)$ for all $m\in M$ and all $n_1,n_2\in N$; (4) $\varphi(m,rn)=r\varphi(m,n)$ for all $r\in R$, all $m\in M$, and all $n\in N$.

Comment: Is it how it is defined in Lovett?

Comment: @Kenny Yes, I copied down the whole definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In thm.12.3.3, $R$ should be assumed to be an *associative* $F$-algebra (with identity), hence it is a ring.

In the presence of identity element, every ideal $M$ of an $F$-algebra $R$ is also a submodule (subspace):
$$\lambda\cdot m=[(\lambda\cdot 1),m]\in M$$
for any $m\in M$ and $\lambda\in F$.